# Understanding protractor's use of promises

Tags: javascript, protractor

Essentially I am playing around with getting a library for preconditions set up (think user creation). As protractor is promise-based and [magically does all the wrapping to keep things in order](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md), I thought of using promises for that purpose. I wrote a little sample code but I cannot explain the observed behaviour so maybe someone can help me understand what's going on.

```
function timeout(ms) {
    var promise = protractor.promise.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('qwer');
        promise.fulfill(true);
    }, ms);
    return promise.promise;
}
```

So now the function returns a promise, which I would assume to be usable inline just like so (as all the code supposedly gets wrapped in a control flow)

```
describe('test', function() {
  it('bla', function() {
    browser.get('/');
    timeout(5000);
    $('some-element').click();
  });
});
```

however this does not work as expected (i.e. the console.log never happens). Even when `expect`ing the result from that promise, it does not change the results. If actually explicitly waiting for done by doing `timeout(5000).then(done)`, the timeout completes, but the next action is not queued to after that action (i.e. site gets opened, element clicked, then after 5 seconds the log from timeout happens).

So I am really confused how the claims of using a control flow to make sure everything gets executed in order and the observed behaviour fit together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough just to create a `protractor.promise` deferred object - you need to tell the control flow about it. This is usually done with `protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute()`.

```
function timeout(ms) {
  protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('qwer');
      deferred.fulfill(true);
    }, ms);
    return deferred.promise;
  });
}
```

Read through https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/promise.js for all the magic behind the scenes here.

Comment: just two months later I finally managed to look at your solution and it works (except you need to write ```controlFlow()```). Thx a lot :)