# protractor does not return proper values when locating element thro CSS

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have the following code

```
            map['alarmName'] =element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h4')).getText();
            map['siteName'] = element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h5')).getText();
            map['timeStamp'] = element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-right > div > h4')).getText();
            map['status'] = element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-right > div > h5:nth-child(2)')).getText();
            map['owner'] = element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-right > div > h5:nth-child(3)')).getText();
```

---

i am hoping to get the text for all the tags above but when i run this protractor test in webstorm , i get the following as results

---

```
alarmName { then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }

siteName { then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }

timeStamp { then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }

status { then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

i have verified that the element exists by running it chrome console and nthAlarm is defined.but not sure what i am doing wrong.

any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks.

---

ok i rewrote my code as

```
this.getAlarmDetailsFromUnclaimedAlarms = function (nthAlarm) {

    var map = new Object();
    // as per the DOM, this is needed. So, first alarm should have nthAlarm value as 2 and so on.
    var nthAlarm = nthAlarm+1;




    browser.sleep(10000);

/*  element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h4'))
        .className.then(function(className) {
            map['severity'] = className;
        });*/


    element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h4'))
        .getText().then(function(text){
            map['severity'] = text;
        });


    element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h5'))
        .getText().then(function(text){
            map['alarmName'] = text;
        });

    element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-right > div > h4'))
        .getText().then(function(text){
            map['timeStamp'] = text;
        });

    element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-right > div > h5:nth-child(2)'))
        .getText().then(function(text){
            map['status'] = text;
        });



    console.log("the value is ",map['status']);
    return map;

};
```

when i run this code it returns UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 0):

`getText` returns a promise to get the text.  It doesn't actually return the text.  Read https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md.

You could try something like:

```
 element(by.css('div.col-md-4.alarms-list-container.ng-scope > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child('+nthAlarm+') > a > div.col-md-5.pull-left > h4'))
    .getText().then(function(actualText) { 
       map['alarmName'] = actualText;
    });
```

Comment: thanks P.T, getting undefined in console.log as above...any thoughts?

Comment: Please read the control-flow doc I linked.  Functions in protractor don't *do* things, they *schedule* things to be done later.  Your `console.log` is happening before any of the assignments complete.  You will probably want to create a "defer", resolve it and return that.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970684/understanding-protractors-use-of-promises/27028884#27028884 and several other, existing questions on StackOverflow.